# Publish non-string message in Cloud PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Almost all of the examples of pub/sub available over web uses String messages.

How do I publish message other than text messages like Java Object, JSON or AVRO to topic and then consume it through subscription.

Many Thanks Pari

Answer (score 7):

The following code lets you publish a message in Pub/Sub using JSON:

```
topic_path = 'your-topic-id'

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

record = {
    'Key1': 'Value1',
    'Key2': 'Value2',
    'Key3': 'Value3',
    'Key4': 'Value4'
}

data = json.dumps(record).encode("utf-8")
future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
print(f'published message id {future.result()}')
```

I hope that It helps you.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. All the others are workarounds.

Comment: To consume this in a cloud function it's `json.loads(base64.b64decode(cloud_event.data["message"]["data"]).decode())` as [per docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#preparing_the_application)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot really do that directly, as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publish-messages-to-a-topic) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage) the published message has to be a bytestring. What you can do instead is load your file, encode it to `utf-8` and then publish it. Afterwards, when pulling, you can dump the message data to a file. For instance, using python for json, you would need to publish like so:

```
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project, topic_name)

with open(json_path) as f:
    data = str(json.load(f))

data = data.encode('utf-8')
publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)
```

Then you can pull and dump like so:

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
    project, subscription_name)

def callback(message):
    with open('received_message.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(message.data, outfile)

subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I guess, there could be better options. Lets wait for more suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

publish JSON with Node - [publishMessage](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/pubsub/latest/Topic.html#publishMessage):

```
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub')
const pubsub = new PubSub()

const json = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

await pubsub.topic('my-topic').publishMessage({json})
```

Answer (score 0):

***As of this writing***

The node.js @google-cloud/pubsub library [only accepts buffer objects](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2403#issuecomment-310071541) and you'll need to stringify.

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/master/samples/topics.js

```
async function publishMessage(topicName, data) {

  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

  // Creates a client
  const pubsub = new PubSub();

  // Publishes the message as a string, e.g. "Hello, world!" or JSON.stringify(someObject)
  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);

  const messageId = await pubsub
    .topic(topicName)
    .publisher()
    .publish(dataBuffer);
  console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
}
```

---

***This might change soon!***

Please follow this request/issue: 
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/121

The library may soon be modified to accept non buffer objects and buffer them for you.